# Carrying style IDs/names from HTML to .docx?

Tags: lua, docx, pandoc

Is it possible to somehow tell `pandoc` to carry the names of styles from original HTML to .docx?

I understand that in order to tune the actual styles, I should be using `reference.docx` file generated by `pandoc`. However, `reference.docx` is limited to what styles it has to: headings, body text, block text, etc.

I'd like to:

1. specify "myStyle" style in the input HTML (via a "class" attribute, via any other HTML attribute or even via a filter code written in Lua),

   ```
   <html>
     <body>
       <p>Hello</p>
       <p class="myStyle">World!</p>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. add a custom "myStyle" to `reference.docx` using Word,
3. run a `html->docx` conversion an expect `pandoc` generate a paragraph element with "myStyle" (instead of `BodyText`, which I believe it sets by [default](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/41d1ae0fdde099bd902607c577a6eca5a9ed3f22/data/docx/word/styles.xml#L23)), so the end result looks like this (contents of `word/document.xml` inside the resulting `output.docx` was cut for brevity):

   ```
   <w:p>
     <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="BodyText" />
     </w:pPr>
     <w:r>
       <w:txml:space="preserve">Hello</w:t>
     </w:r>
   </w:p>
   <w:p>
     <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="myStyle" />
     </w:pPr>
     <w:r>
       <w:txml:space="preserve">World!</w:t>
     </w:r>
   </w:p>
   ```

There's [some evidence](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/search?q=styleid&unscoped_q=styleid) `styleId` can be [passed around](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/5a20cc07ddee4115bee48ceabe890f0d490d9a62/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docx.hs#L618), but I don't really understand it and am unable to find any documentation about it.

Doc on [filtering in Lua](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.div) states you can access `attrs` when manipulating a `pandoc.div`, but it says nothing about whether any of the attrs will be interpreted by pandoc in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, found what I needed – [Custom styles](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#output). It's limited, but better than what I arrived earlier, and of course much better than nothing at all :)

I'll leave a step-by-step guide here in case anyone stumbles upon a similar question.

First, generate a `reference.docx` file like this:

```
pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > styles.docx
```

Then open the file in MS Word (I was using a macOS version) you'll see this:

[image]

Click the "New style..." button on the right, and create a style to your liking. In my case I made change the style of text to be bold, in blue color:

[image]

Since I am converting from HTML to DOCX, here's my `input.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>Page 1</div>
    <div custom-style="eugene-is-testing">Page 2</div>
    <div>Page 3</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run:

```
pandoc --standalone --reference-doc styles.docx --output output.docx input.html
```

Finally, enjoy the result:

[image]